# change stage size in flash but keeping aspect ratio?

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating an iOs APP in adobe flash cs6 and everything works fine.

however the issue that I have now is the content of the app gets stretched in bigger iPhones like iPhone 5!

I am using the following code in my AS3 code on the first frame of the first layer:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Screen;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.system.Capabilities;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.geom.*;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_BORDER;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
```

I am using the code above so the entire APP will fit every screen and it works fine but everything (the content of the APP) gets stretched!

is there anything i can do to keep the aspect ratio of the content while fitting the APP to every screen like my code above?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I've removed the `stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;` and when i viewed the APP in the iphone, it doesn't get stretched BUT everything's slightly gone to the right which result in hiding the small part of the APP on the right side of the screen!

Comment: what you are asking for, is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Despite Daniel is right, a more detailed answer is needed.

The truth is that this is a bit more sophisticated than you think. There is no way that Flash knows how to position your elements - sometimes you would like your button to stretch, but not that much. Or to keep it's aspect ratio, but then some of the content will fall out.

How it's usually done? The best practices in this field is to have a fixed stage viewport (initial stage size). Usually this is fixed at 320x480. Then, you let your app stretch this (if you run a bigger screen, your 320 pixels would be awfully scaled, and so pixelized).

Here comes the tricky part - depending on device resolution and dpi, you provide specific assets. Let's say you run your app on device that is **twice** your 'initial fixed viewport'. Then everything will seems zoomed twice (640x960 is twice 320x480). Everything is in pixels.

But here you provide graphics that are also **twice** as big - 640x960. This means that if you run them on the basic stage, they will be **downsized** - becoming 320x480. But if you run them on a bigger screen, the stage gets zoomed in (as talked before), and the graphics now become **their actual size**.

Imagine that each phone has the same display size (let's say 4 inches). But every one has different resolution - 320x840, 640x960, 720x1280, and so on. So if you want your app to look **exactly** the same, having a button that is 100% wide - then provide a graphic for it that is 100% of the resolution! So your graphic should come in different sized for each display - 320px, 640px, etc.

Of course you cannot match **all** the devices. So here comes 'aspect ration' - a number that indicates how much the screen is bigger. If your base is 320x480, and you run on 640x960, your aspect ratio would be 2. So you get your assets from folder 'assetsx2' (or whatever you call it, as long as you got some system to read it). If you run on different display and the ration gets for example 2.8, you would round it to 3. This way images would get a little scaled, **but** scaling 3 to 2.8 is better than scaling 3 to 1, right? The more you scale, the blurry it gets.

I'm sorry for the long answer, but I tried to explain it not very technical. There are great articles about that. These two resources helped me the most when I started:

http://sebastien-gabriel.com/designers-guide-to-dpi/home - info what's going on
http://screensiz.es/phone - info about different devices, their size, resolution, aspect ratio, and info about how your folder should be named (there are conventions).

Hope that helps! :)

p.s.
Forgot to add that this is all about graphics, having in mind that you build an UI maybe, so you use graphics. Despite that, the whole idea works no matter what kind of graphics you use - you just need to work with fixed size stage, position everything according to it, and then think of the scale factor. So for having a 100% wide button on 640px wide screen, instead of making it 620px wide with 10px margins on each side, you make it 310px with 5 px margin on each side.

Comment: thanks. but only this line of code works for me: stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_BORDER; my app now works on iphone 4 and 5 very nicely..

Answer (score -1):

no.

There's no way to magically deal with this. You have to tell it how to arrange the content.

Comment: how can I tell it to keep the content's aspect ratio ?

Comment: setting a stage.scaleMode does not have a cumulative effect. look at the options here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageScaleMode.html   most likely you're looking for `SHOW_ALL`

Comment: You see, i did try SHOW_ALL too but as it stated in that link you sent above " Borders can appear on two sides of the application." I cannot have Borders around the app!

Comment: Get rid of stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;  You want NO_SCALE so it doesn't resize.

Comment: @moot, if I use NO_SCALE, because its an iOs APP, the stage will fit the iPhone's screen but the content wont and this will leave the APP with 2 white bars (the actual stage) at the top and bottom of the APP.

Comment: Yes.  You need to check the size of the screen (Capabilities.screenResolutionX) and change your content to match.  You size everything with code.